# Como montar números de código de barra de GPS?

Tags: gps

Como montar números de código de barra de GPS? Alguma sugestão?

(GPS - Guia da Previdência Social)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Os códigos barras seguem padrões, alguns deles são:

> Code 39
>   Code 128
>   EAN 8
>   EAN 13
>   EAN 128
>   Codabar

Primeiramente você deve saber se para a sua aplicação em questão não existe uma convenção que define qual é o padrão mais apropriado.

Você não precisar criar um gerador de códigos de barras você mesmo, pois já existe milhares de aplicações pelo internet, como por exemplo [nesse site](http://www.invertexto.com/codigo-barras). Ao acessá-lo, é só escolher o padrão de código de barras que você achar melhor, preencher as configurações e informar o valor que quer transformar em código de barras.

Atente-se que alguns padrões de códigos de barra tem algumas restrições, como por exemplo o EAN 8 cria apenas código de barras para 8 números, sendo que o oitavo é o dígito verificador. Já outros padrões podem aceitar letras e uma quantidade variável de caracteres no seu valor a ser transformado.

Comment: Pelos testes que fiz acredito ser UPC_A, o problema maior é identificar todos os números correspondentes, alguns sei que é o valor do INSS, outros o CNPJ da empresa, data de competência , mas alguns são distintos.

Comment: Desculpa mas não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: preciso passar números para o método , assim gerando o código de barras (85840000015-9) . Porem são 44 numeros ao todo e entre eles estão o valor do INSS , valor x e Y, e outros numeros eu não tenho a mínima ideia de onde vem.

Comment: Veja se esse link ajuda: http://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/previdencia/gps/OrientPreench.htm